# In React JS, using react-select want to set options to default value after checkbox unchecked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to, disable select list after unchecking checkbox and resetting the select value to default..but I am seeing the one I selected. I am using React-select for the select and options in this.

APP.js

````
const adultOptions = [{ value: '1', label: '1' },{ value: '2', label: '2' }];
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    disableSelect2: true
  }

  selectDisableHandler2 = () => {
    const showSelect = this.state.disableSelect2;
    this.setState({ disableSelect2: !showSelect });

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="Container">
          <div>
            <table style={{ borderStyle: "solid" }}>
              <caption style={{ borderStyle: "inherit" }}>
                <input type="checkbox" 
                onClick={this.selectDisableHandler2} />Room 2</caption>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th>Adult (18+)</th>
                  <th>Children (0-17)</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                  <Select
                    options={adultOptions} 
                    isDisabled={this.state.disableSelect2}
                    defaultValue={this.state.disableSelect2 ? adultOptions[0] : null}/>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
       </div>       
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

```[In the image after unchecking checkbox, the options value is set to "2" which I selected, but I wanted it to be default value i.e. "1" ][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5gjP.png
````

Comment: Share an interactive code, like `adultOptions
` to test.

Comment: @ZeyadEtman added adultoptions

Comment: What about this `onChange` from the select? The `onChange` should be a function

Comment: @mthrsj removed onChange and changed defaultValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the value of your select in your components state:

```
<Select
  value={this.state.selectedOption}
  isDisabled={this.state.disableSelect2}
  options={adultOptions}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

Have the checkbox handler update it accordingly:

```
selectDisableHandler2 = () => {
  const showSelect = this.state.disableSelect2;
  this.setState({
    disableSelect2: !showSelect,
    selectedOption:
      showSelect === true ? this.state.selectedOption : adultOptions[0]
  });
};
```

Codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/6l2171x37n